# Running Wordpress repo locally through MAMP. Assets not being pulled in

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, mamp

Currently I am trying to run a Wordpress repo locally for development. I am not using MAMP pro even though I still have a 9 day trail. I figured since I'm going to be using the free version for now I might as well work with that. I have my Apache & MySQL server running along with the `Document Root` pointing to my Sites folder where my projectName repo sits. I'm still running off of the default port of Apache 8888.

After I start the servers, I open WebStart and import my DB into phpMyAdmin. Everything works perfectly fine and the copy of my db gets imported. I then make sure that my `wp-config.php` file has the appropriate settings to access this db. I then click on `My Website`. This pulls up the content of the website. However, it does not pull in any of the assets(imgs/js/css). I receive the following errors in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE http://projectName.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/logo-footer-1.png 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE http://projectName.dev/wp-content/themes/projectName/images/circle.png
```

And so the list goes on and on for pretty much every asset the project could possibly have. Now configuration is NOT my strong suit, and at this point I am at a loss of what could possibly be happening. Awhile ago I did follow a [tutorial](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew) on how to setup my files so that I can access them in the web browser by simply typing the name of the project with the domain .dev, example: `projectName.dev`. I started having issues with this after upgrading to OS Sierra and it no longer works. Could this possibly be the reason as to why it is looking for these assets in the projectName at the .dev domain?

I apologize if this does not make sense. I am willing to provide anyone with any information on this as I need as much help as possible because I still need to level up my configuration skills. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images and other assets are referenced with an absolute filepath (i.e. the URL of the server on which you first set it up). This has to be changed in all database entries. There are tutorials for this on the net, but the most simple version is to open the sql file in an editor and search & replace the general URL part in the complete database.

Be sure to keep a backup of the file - that might not work on the first try...

Comment: Are there any tutorials that come to mind that you would suggest? I'll start with trying to open the sql file in an editor and search & replace the general URL part in the complete database.

Comment: Now when I go to my website through `MAMP` it displays `http://localhost:8888/` as my url. So what would I need to change the file paths to? A little slow at understanding so forgive me. 

Thanks for taking the time to help as well.

Comment: In your example you'd have to replace the string `http://projectName.dev/` (that's what you wrote in your question, I suppose the real URL is different) with `http://localhost:8888/` Everything after that, like `uploads/...`, `content/themes/...` remains untouched (so be careful not to include any spaces by accident). And don't limit the replace function to whole words - you are replacing *parts* of URLs

Comment: I just did that right before you answer and came to post I figured it out! @Johannes, thank you so much for your help. Something that seemed probably so simple to you was racking my brain! If I have any other questions I'll be sure to return. Thanks!